# Getting info from exception without sys.exc_info

Tags: python, exception

I am trying to get more information out of an exception object, `err`, beyond its error message. In my code I sometimes capture exceptions deep in some subfunction. Back at the top level I want to print info about where the exception occurred etc.

I have seen similar questions where the answers involve using `sys.exc_info`, but according to the docs, this is too limited:

> Return information about the most recent exception caught by an except
>   clause in the current stack frame or in an older stack frame.

whereas I want to get this information from an arbitrary exception object captured and stored at some unknowable point in the program execution, with possibly multiple exceptions being raised at later points.

The information seems to be in there; if I issue `raise err` it all comes out. But I cannot figure out how to pry it out of the exception object without `rais`ing it. Can I somehow capture the output from `raise` in a string and print that?

Comment: Until it is raised, an exception is just a regular object.

Comment: Yes, that's why I am asking. How can I inspect this object to find line numbers etc?

Comment: Line number of what? It can't be the line the exception was raised

Comment: And why is that? If I raise the exception manually it tells me where it was first raised, which is what I am looking for.

Comment: Because you're asking about exceptions that were not raised.

Comment: The exception was raised, then captured. I want to get the trace information from where it was first raised. As I said, if I re-raise it, the info is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`traceback`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html) module:

```
>>> import traceback
>>> try:
...   raise Exception()
... except Exception as e:
...   print(traceback.extract_tb(e.__traceback__))
... 
[('<stdin>', 2, '<module>', None)]
```

(2 is the line number)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

This gives the same output as `sys.exc_info`, but for arbitrary exception:

```py
def exc_info(exc):
    return type(exc), exc, exc.__traceback__
```